# How does the fork() function behave in if statements?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, fork

How is the fork() call working over here? I tried to understand it using print statements but I got more confused with it. I know that !fork() checks if it is a child process meaning fork()==0 & if (fork()) means if it is a parent process. I don't get how we end up with this output. If someone can give explanation, it would clear my doubts about fork calls in if statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int x = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t p = getpid();
    x++;
    fork();

    if (!fork())
    {

        if (fork())
        {
            x++;

        }
        x++;
    }

    printf("p%d: x = %d\n", getpid() - p, x);
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p0: x = 1
p1: x = 1
p2: x = 3
p4: x = 2
p3: x = 3
p5: x = 2
```

Comment: Just walk through the code on a piece of paper. Every time you hit a `fork` statement, work out both the parent and the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think about the `fork()` calls in the `if`, think about what `fork()`
actually does.

`fork()` is a function that *creates  a  new  process  by duplicating the
calling process* (see `man 2 fork`). That means that when you call `fork()`
and assuming that the call didn't fail, then you will have two processes, the
original process and a new one that is a copy of the original one. What does
"copy" mean? It means that the memory and the point where the process resumes
working are the same (in reality is copy means more, but I try to keep it
simple).

Now that there are 2 processes, both resume working at the same point.
But they differ at one crucial point: the return value of the `fork()` call:

- the parent (aka original) get the pid of the forked process
- the child (aka copy) get 0 from the forked process

That's the only way to distinguish the parent from the child. So when you work
with `fork`, you should use this pattern:

```c
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid < 0)
{
    // ABORT, ERROR
    // no processes created
}

if(pid == 0)
{
    // CHILD PROCESS
} else {
    // PARENT PROCESS

    // at some point, parent needs to wait for the child
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);  // see man 2 waitpid for more info on that
}
```

So, let's take a look at your code:

- At the first `fork()` the value of `x` is 1. Both processes keep running.
  Let's call the parent process `A` and the child process `B`.
- At the second `fork()` `A` and `B` spawns new processes, let's forget about
  them for a second. In case of `A`, the second `fork()` returns the pid of the
  next process (`C`, child of `A`) and because of the `!` the expression evaluates to 0, so the
  inner inner statement does not get executed for `A`, which jumps to the `printf` line which prints 1.
- The same applies for `B` as it a copy of `A`.
- Now let's consider the second `fork()`.
- We know that `A` spawns a second child, `C`. We know what happened to `A`
  afterwards. But the `fork()` call in `C` returns 0, so `!` evaluates it to 1
  and the inner `if` statement gets executed.
- Now it calls `fork()` again, here `C` spawns `D` but the `fork()` call of C gets
  the pid of `D`, the if evaluates to true and executed `x++` and after that
  again `x++`. So when it finally prints the value of x, you get 3. Because we
  are talking about `C`, the grandchild of `A`, `getpid() - p` is 2.
- etc.

I'm not going to keep unraveling the `fork()` calls, but now that you know how
`fork()` behaves, take a pencil and piece of paper and continue doing it.
You'll see that the values in the prints match.

**edit**:

I suggest that you read the man page for `fork()`. Open a terminal and type

`man 2 fork`

it explains at greater detail how `fork()` works and what a copy means.

You should also read the man page of `waitpid`. You need to call that unless
you want to have zombies processes.

Answer (score 1):

to your question, how was the output achieved?

following discussion assumes `fork()` always successful

```
fork();
// now have both parent and child processes

if (!fork())
// total of 4 processes
// now have a parent and a child process for each of the prior parent and child process 
// but only the two child processes are executing inside this `if` body
{

    if (fork())
    // now have 6 processes
    // now have another parent and child process for each of the prior processes 
    // but only the two new parent processes are executing inside this `if` body
    {
        x++;
    }
```

do you need further details?

Comment: Im not trying to write the correct code, but I want to understand how the output was achieved.

Answer (score 0):

After executing the first `fork();` call you now have two processes running.

After executing `if (!fork())` you now have four processes (because the first two got forked). However the body of the if condition will only be executed in two of them (the child processes). This means that `x` will be incremented within the body of the if condition in only two processes.

Then, after executing `if (fork())` those two child processes get forked themselves, which means that you now have a total of six processes. But `x` only gets incremented in the two parent processes, giving it the final value of 3 in those two processes.